# Is this a memory leak?

Tags: apex

I using apex:actionPoller to refresh a VF page and wonder if I'm causing a memory leak because I call new on every getRecords() call.  The VF page is:

```
<apex:page controller="casePollList" >  
  <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock id="myBlock" >
    <apex:actionPoller interval="10" rerender="myBlock" />
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!cases}" var="c" id="myTable">
       <apex:column value="{!c.CaseNumber}"/>
       <apex:column value="{!c.Subject}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
  </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The standard list controller code is:

```
public class casePollList {

    public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon {
    get {
        setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
                [SELECT Subject, CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE owner.name='Open Cases']));
        return setCon;
    }
    set;
    }

    // Initialize setCon and return a list of records
    public List<Case> getCases() {
        return (List<Case>) setCon.getRecords();
    }        
}
```

Comment: How do you define a memory leak? Are you receiving any error messages? Poor performance over a period of time? Are you just trying to ascertain if this is an efficient mechanism for showing Cases in a periodically-refreshing page?

Comment: Apex uses (JVM) garbage collection where memory that is no longer referenced is automatically freed. So if you added each new set controller to a list you would run out if memory. But you are replacing the previous reference in `setCon` with a new one so you should be OK.

Comment: @Keith C Makes sense.  I figured as much but didn't want to assume so.  Create it as a response and I'll mark it as an answer.

Comment: @MarkPond No known error messages but this seemed like bad (or at least lazy) programming practice.  I welcome other approaches although I did try apex:enhancedList and Streaming API based ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apex uses (JVM) garbage collection where memory that is no longer referenced is automatically freed. So if you added each new set controller to a list you would run out if memory. But you are replacing the previous reference in `setCon` with a new one so you should be OK.

More generally in Salesforce memory is discarded at the end of a request. Your case is relatively unusual where you are making the request back to the same controller so the view state is being (probably unnecessarily) shuffled backwards and forwards and so could potentially build up unwanted objects.